# functional square root problem - Solution with "Chain Solution". - 2 example problems: $f(f(x))=x^2-2$, $f(f(x))-x^2+x+3=0$ + 1 more problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

> ***Is there a function / Are there such functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(f(x))=x^2-2$?***

**My Solution:**

\begin{align}
&\text{Let's look for $t_2$ which satisfies } f^2(t_2)=t_2. \\
&\Rightarrow t_2=2, -1. \\
\ \\
&\text{Now, let's look for $t_4$ which satisfies } f^4(t_4)=t_4. \\
&\Rightarrow f^4(t_4)=f^2(t_4^2-2) = t_4^4-4t_4^2+2. \\
&\text{let set }T_2 = \{t_2\}, T_4=\{t_4\}. \\
&\Rightarrow T_2 \subset T_4. \\
&n(T_4)=4, n(T_2)=2. \Rightarrow \text{let } T_4=\{2, -1, \alpha, \beta \}. (\alpha, \beta \not\in T_2.) \\
\ \\
&\text{I will define the $2$chain, $-1$chain, $\alpha$chain and $\beta$chain:} \\
\ \\
&\text{$2$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} 2 & \rightarrow & f(2) \\ \uparrow & 
\fbox{$2_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f(2) &\leftarrow &  2 \end{bmatrix} \\
\ \\
-&\text{$1$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} -1 & \rightarrow & f(-1) \\ \uparrow & \fbox{$2_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f(-1) & \leftarrow &  -1 \end{bmatrix} \\
\ \\
&\text{$\alpha$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \rightarrow & f(\alpha) \\ \uparrow & \fbox{$4_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f^3(\alpha) & \leftarrow & f^2(\alpha) \end{bmatrix} \\
\ \\
&\text{$\beta$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} \beta & \rightarrow & f(\beta) \\ \uparrow & \fbox{$4_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f^3(\beta) & \leftarrow &  f^2(\beta) \end{bmatrix} \\
\ \\
&\text{Let's look at $\alpha$chain.} \\
\ \\
&\text{if } f(\alpha)=\alpha \Rightarrow f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\alpha)=2 \Rightarrow f^3(\alpha)=2, f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\alpha)=-1 \Rightarrow f^3(\alpha)=-1, f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\alpha)=\beta \Rightarrow \text{Let's look at $\beta$chain together.} \\
\ \\
&\text{if } f(\beta)=\beta \Rightarrow f^2(\beta)=\beta, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\beta)=2 \Rightarrow f^3(\beta)=2, f^2(\beta)=\beta, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\beta)=-1 \Rightarrow f^3(\beta)=-1, f^2(\beta)=\beta, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\beta)=\alpha \Rightarrow \text{Going back to the $\alpha$chain, } f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\
\ \\
&\therefore \not\exists f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t. } f(f(x))=x^2-2.
\end{align}

P.S.

1. You can prove this with $f^3(\alpha)$, too. I recommend trying this!

---

---

---

---

> ***Prove that there isn't such function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(f(x))-x^2+x+3=0$.***

**My Solution:**

\begin{align}
&\text{Let's take a look at $t_2$ which satisfies $f^2(t_2)=t_2$.} \\
&\Rightarrow t_2^2-2t_2-3=0, t_2=-1, 3. \\
\ \\
&\text{Now, let]s take a look at $t_4$ which satisfies $f^4(t_4)=t_4$.} \\
&\Rightarrow (t_4^2-t_4-3)^2-(t_4^2-t_4-3)-3=t_4. \\
&\therefore t_4 \text{ has $4$ solution.}\\
\ \\
&\text{let set $T_2=\{t_2\}$, $T_4=\{t_4\}$.} \\
&T_2 \subset T_4, \ n(T_2)=2, \ n(T_4)=4. \Rightarrow T_2=\{-1, 3\}, T_4=\{-1, 3, \alpha, \beta \} (\alpha, \beta \neq -1, 3.) \\
\ \\
&\text{Now, I will define $-1$chain, $3$chain, $\alpha$chain and $\beta$chain:} \\
\ \\
-&\text{$1$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} -1 & \rightarrow & f(-1) \\ \uparrow & \fbox{$2_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f(-1) & \leftarrow &  -1 \end{bmatrix} \\
\ \\
&\text{$3$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} 3 & \rightarrow & f(3) \\ \uparrow & 
\fbox{$2_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f(3) & \leftarrow &  3 \end{bmatrix} \\
\ \\
&\text{$\alpha$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \rightarrow & f(\alpha) \\ \uparrow & \fbox{$4_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f^3(\alpha) & \leftarrow & f^2(\alpha) \end{bmatrix} \\
\ \\
&\text{$\beta$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} \beta & \rightarrow & f(\beta) \\ \uparrow & \fbox{$4_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f^3(\beta) & \leftarrow &  f^2(\beta) \end{bmatrix} \\
\ \\
&\text{Let's look at $\alpha$chain.} \\
\ \\
&\text{if } f(\alpha)=\alpha \Rightarrow f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\alpha)=-1 \Rightarrow f^3(\alpha)=-1, f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\alpha)=3 \Rightarrow f^3(\alpha)=3, f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\alpha)=\beta \Rightarrow \text{Let's look at $\beta$chain together.} \\
\ \\
&\text{if } f(\beta)=\beta \Rightarrow f^2(\beta)=\beta, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\beta)=-1 \Rightarrow f^3(\beta)=-1, f^2(\beta)=\beta, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\beta)=3 \Rightarrow f^3(\beta)=3, f^2(\beta)=\beta, \text{Contradiction.} \\
&\text{if } f(\beta)=\alpha \Rightarrow \text{Going back to the $\alpha$chain, } f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\
\ \\
&\therefore \not\exists f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t. } f(f(x))-x^2+x+3=0.
\end{align}

***P.S. If you want, you can try solving this one with a chain solution:***

> ***$$f(f(x))=x^2-14x+56.$$***

***Check your Solution:***

> \begin{align} &\text{Let's look for $t_2$ which satisfies $f^2(t_2)=t_2.$} \\ &\Rightarrow t_2=7, 8. \\ \ \\ &\text{Now, let's look for $t_4$ which satisfies $f^4(t_4)=t_4.$} \\ &\Rightarrow f^4(t_4)=f^2(t_4^2-14t_4+56)=(t_4^2-14t_4+56)^2-14(t_4^2-14t_4+56)+56. \\ & \therefore \text{$t_4$ has $4$ solution.} \\ \ \\ &\text{let set $T_2=\{t_2\}$, $T_4=\{t_4\}$.} \\ &\Rightarrow n(T_2)=2, n(T_4)=4, T_2 \subset T_4. \Rightarrow \text{let }T_4-T_2=\{\alpha, \beta \}. \\ & \Rightarrow T_2=\{7, 8\}, T_4=\{7, 8, \alpha, \beta \}. \\ \ \\ &\text{I will define the $7$chain, $8$chain, $\alpha$chain and $\beta$chain:}\\ \ \\ & \text{$7$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} 7 & \rightarrow & f(7) \\ \uparrow & \fbox{$2_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f(7) &\leftarrow &  7 \end{bmatrix} \\ \ \\ &\text{$8$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} 8 & \rightarrow & f(8) \\ \uparrow & \fbox{$2_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f(8) &\leftarrow &  8 \end{bmatrix} \\ \ \\ &\text{$\alpha$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \rightarrow & f(\alpha) \\ \uparrow & \fbox{$4_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f^3(\alpha) & \leftarrow & f^2(\alpha) \end{bmatrix} \\ \ \\ &\text{$\beta$chain}: \begin{bmatrix} \beta & \rightarrow & f(\beta) \\ \uparrow & \fbox{$4_\text{cyc}$} & \downarrow \\ f^3(\beta) & \leftarrow &  f^2(\beta) \end{bmatrix} \\ \ \\ &\text{if } f(\alpha)=\alpha \Rightarrow f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\&\text{if } f(\alpha)=7 \Rightarrow f^3(\alpha)=7,f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\&\text{if } f(\alpha)=8 \Rightarrow f^3(\alpha)=8, f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\ &\text{if } f(\alpha)=\beta \Rightarrow \text{Let's look at $\beta$chain together.} \\ \ \\ &\text{if } f(\beta)=\beta \Rightarrow f^2(\beta)=\beta, \text{Contradiction.} \\ &\text{if } f(\beta)=7 \Rightarrow f^3(\beta)=7, f^2(\beta)=\beta, \text{Contradiction.} \\ &\text{if } f(\beta)=8 \Rightarrow f^3(\beta)=8, f^2(\beta)=\beta, \text{Contradiction.} \\ &\text{if } f(\beta)=\alpha \Rightarrow \text{Going back to the $\alpha$chain, } f^2(\alpha)=\alpha, \text{Contradiction.} \\ \ \\ \end{align}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the functional equation $ f(f(x))=ax^2+bx+c $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595127/how-to-solve-the-functional-equation-ffx-ax2bxc)

Comment: @JeanMarie Umm... I can't find the chain-solution. I posted this to show the chain solution, which is interesting.

Comment: But you don't mention neither in your title nor in your text that you want to solve this issue by a specific method... This reference has the advantage that it encompasses your 2 questions...

Comment: @JeanMarie I edited about it.

Comment: You address in your two questions a general question called "**functional square root problem**". Your method is interesting but be conscious that there are a lot of other approches. See for example the answer of @Will Jagy to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421025/functional-square-root-of-fx-x2-1)

Comment: @JeanMarie Alright, I've seen lots of other solutions about this. Again, I'm posting this one to let people know about this fun and simple solution.

Comment: Therefore, if I understand well, it isn't really a question, but an opportunity you take to show us a seemilingly new method, why not (though I think your previous "question" was enough for this objective). **It could be turned into a question** : you could ask is : "is it an **original method**", or if such is not the case, can somebody give  a reference to previous works along these lines ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I was trying to show how it works with an example. I can't generalize this solution with $ax^2+bx+c$. So, I was uploading various kinds of example of this solution, which I call "Chain Solution".

Comment: You could use the term "[functional square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/469549)" in your title. It would help to make your question more "attractive" for future searchs and therefore make "advertising" for it :)

Comment: Reacting to your last comment: good idea, but why don't you group these questions into a single one ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Alright, I'll try it. I'll add the previous one to this post.

Comment: @JeanMarie I edited it. Do you have any other things to edit? Please tell me if there is.

Comment: I agree with a comment on the previous question that the "chain" notation could be better. $x\to f(x)\to f^2(x)\to f^3(x)\to x$, for example. The notation you have tried looks like the notation for a matrix with the specified elements in the four corners, where the "$\ldots$" indicate some number of rows or columns that are to be filled in somehow. And of course your method has nothing to do with such a matrix.

Comment: 1) It's fine like this. You should take also into account the proposal for a change into notations by David K. 2) Besides, can I ask you whether you do this work in the framework of some mathematical studies or is it for your own interest ?

Comment: 1) Alright, I'll change it.
2) I'm just posting these questions or my solution for "just interest", not for the studies!

Comment: @DavidK Edited it!

Comment: It seems to me that your idea of "chains" is the same as the one presented [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1349836p7366628) on AOPS, or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/481034/229831) on MSE.

Comment: I congratulate you for having patiently transformed your question according to our remarks with a constructive dialog ! Will be happy to find you back for ulterior questions.

Comment: Although a previous comment points to places with a similar idea, I found the presentation in this question (after the recent edits) to be possibly more intuitive.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari I just wanted to put the idea with virtual expression, so that people can understand easier.